# Did they break Suzanne in Blender 4.1?

Tags: modeling, suzanne

I just downloaded Blender 4.1 and here is how Suzanne looks like. Applying `Shade Smooth` totally destroys the marked area under the eye.

#aheartforsuzanne

[image]

Comment: If you go into Edit mode, select a vert on an eye, then hit L you'll see that it's just one of the verts from the eye sticking out slightly which you can see more clearly in wireframe view (Shift-Z). It's actually the same in 4.02 and 3.6.10, but I guess that the change to Smooth Shading in 4.1 is causing the issue. Most people won't notice it because they stick a Subdiv surface modifier on Suzanne first.